# jQuery "this" issue

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to pass a value to a function.

```
<div class="the_service" id="ecommerce" onClick="javascript: gorightthere(ecommerce);"> 

function gorightthere(this){

    var gothere = $('h2[name="'+this+'"]');
    if (gothere.length){
$('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: gothere.offset().top
                     }, 2000);
        removeClass('selected');
        gothere.addClass('selected');
    }
};
```

What I am trying to do is to pass the value "ecommerce" to the function. I want to use "this" because I have many different values to pass, and I want to do a function that will work with every value I will pass after the onClick event.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: you don't need to include `javascript:` in front of your js

Answer (score 7):

Your variable name is conflicting with the reserved keyword `this`. Use another variable name and you should be all set. In general, you should never use `this` for a variable name, because it has a very specific meaning in almost all C-based languages:

```
function gorightthere(value) {      
    var gothere = $('h2[name="' + value + '"]'); 
    if (gothere.length){ 
        $('html, body').animate({ 
            scrollTop: gothere.offset().top  
            }, 2000); 
        removeClass('selected'); 
        gothere.addClass('selected'); 
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using 'this', why not just use a normal variable as a parameter? This is due to the fact that `this` is a keyword in JS.

Answer (score 1):

'this' is a a reserved keyword, try this code:

```
<div class="the_service" id="ecommerce" onClick="javascript: gorightthere(this);"> 

function gorightthere(element){

    var gothere = $(element);
    if (gothere.length){
$('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: gothere.offset().top
                     }, 2000);
        removeClass('selected');
        gothere.addClass('selected');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you could just reverse your variables like so:
in your div tag change -> javascript: gorightthere(this);
function gorightthere(ecommerce){

```
var gothere = $('h2[name="'+ecommerce.id+'"]');
```

assuming your id in your div to represent the name in your h2 element, otherwise other slight modifications will be need.